# Inverse of a Set-Valued Transformation

Tags: inverse, transformation, inverse-function, set-valued-analysis

How is the inverse of a set-valued transformation defined?

For a function $f$, we know that the inverse exists if and only if $f$ is bijective. However, I have found in a book that the inverse of
$$S:[0,1]\to[0,1], \qquad S(x)=4x(1-x),$$
is given by
$$S^{-1}([0,x])=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x},1\right].$$
It is pretty straightforward to check graphically (by plotting $S(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$) that the inverse is correct. Nevertheless $S$ is clearly not bijective. So what it the characterization of inverse transformations?

I think that my confusion stems from the fact that I am not used to think of functions as set-valued objects.

Comment: This is the pre-image, not the inverse function. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image